# ruby on rails better syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any better way to write this code.I think it seems bad.

```
if !params[:project].blank?
  redirect_to project_path(params[:project])
else
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator:

`redirect_to params[:project].blank? ? root_url : project_path(params[:project])`

Comment: If you want job security and don't like readability, this is the way to go.

Comment: i dont hate this. it is dryer since you don't repeat the redirect stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Reads a bit better, IMO.

```
if params[:project].blank?
  redirect_to root_path
else
  redirect_to project_path(params[:project])
end
```

Comment: Exactly. Never have a double negative condition like you'd have in the `else`: "If project parameters are *not not* blank?" In this revision it's "If project parameters *are* blank?"

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to(
  params[:project]
  .tap{|p| break p.blank? ? root_url : project_path(p)}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very readable 2 liner IMO.

```
redirect_to project_path(params[:project]) unless params[:project].blank?
redirect_to root_url if params[:project].blank?
```